# Typescript compiler wont make up it's mind on null vs undefined for method return

Tags: typescript, null, undefined, prototype, screeps

I am moving some code between existing projects and I am having an issue with typescript complaining about the return type of a method.

I don't know if it is a change in IDE or a compiler option so I can give you the config options if you need them. I'm a Java developer so JS and Typescript are new to me.

An example method is:

```
RoomPosition.prototype.findClosestByRangeThenPath = function <T extends _HasRoomPosition>(objects: T[]): T {
const distances = _.map(objects, obj => this.getRangeTo(obj));
const minDistance = _.min(distances);
if (minDistance > 4) {
    return this.findClosestByRange(objects);
 } else {
    const closestObjects = _.filter(objects, obj => this.getRangeTo(obj) == minDistance);
    return this.findClosestByPath(closestObjects);
 }
};
```

findClosestByRange and findClosestByPath both return `T | null` so I though I could make the method return the same but if I do the IDE is complaining "`Type 'T | null' is not assignable to type 'T | undefined'.`"

My nieve solution is to assign findClosestByRange and findClosestByPath to a return value `ret` and do the following but it just smells bad.

```
if(ret){
      return ret;
  }else {
      return undefined;
  }
```

My questions are:

1. Why is it saying that I need to return undefined when the return types of the methods in the function instead return null?
2. Is there a better way to do it other than my fix above or putting @ts-ignore for each method with this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Edit:
Adding the interface _HasRoomPosition

```
interface _HasRoomPosition {
    pos: RoomPosition;
}
```

For the full api it is here https://docs.screeps.com/api/

Comment: I don't know what `_HasRoomPosition` is, but the return type of `findClosestByRangeThenPath` is `T`, maybe you want it to return `T | null`? It's a guess though, there is not enough information.

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example in a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)? It's hard to know how to help you here as is.

Comment: @DenisFrezzato returning T|null gives "Type 'T | null' is not assignable to type 'T | undefined'."